# is RDD[(K, V)] a type in rdd: RDD[(K, V)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In spark file of /core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala, the has the following

```
implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
      (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null) = {
    new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
  }
```

I think RDD[(K, V)] is a type for paraemter of rdd. However, how could we define a type like RDD[(K, V)]?
The following could NOT be compiled

```
abstract class RDD[(K, V)]
```

But the following could.

```
abstract class RDD[K, V]
```

So what's RDD[(K, V)]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[(K, V)]` is a tuple of K and V, combined as a single argument

[image]

`[K, V]` are two distinct type arguments

[image]

And [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/RDD.html) accepts only a single type argument

Answer (score 5):

`(K, V)` means `Tuple2[K, V]`, so `rdd: RDD[(K, V)]` means `rdd: RDD[Tuple2[K, V]]`. Type `RDD` should have a single type parameter.

```
class RDD[T]
new RDD[(Int, String)] // new RDD[Tuple2[Int, String]]
```